# How can I add a node type to the graph from within a script in booggie 2?

Tags: rule, booggie

Is there are way to access the metamodel, instantiate a node or edge of a specific type and add it to the graph in a script?

Please note: The booggie-project does not exist anymore but led to the development of [Soley Studio](https://www.soley.io/en/pr-soley-studio/) which covers the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the node/edges types from the metamodel using

```py
graph.Model.NodeModel.GetType("MyNodeType")
```

- or -

```py
graph.Model.EdgeModel.GetType("MyEdgeType")
```

Using the method `graph.AddNode` you can add it to the graph and the added node is returned to which attribute assignments can be made.

All together, it looks like this:

```py
    newNode = graph.AddNode(graph.Model.NodeModel.GetType("MyNodeType"))
    newNode.myAttribute = 42
```