# How can I change attributes of a node within a script in booggie 2?

Tags: rule, booggie

As can be seen in this post ([How can I add a node type to the graph from within a script in booggie 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930657/how-can-i-add-a-node-type-to-the-graph-from-within-a-script-in-booggie-2)) it's possible to add nodes/edges to the metamodel in booggie and change their attributes.

Is it also possible to change the attributes of already existing nodes (or edges) in a graph using a script?

Comment: this is a cool question because it shows the potential of using the entire functionality of GrGen's IGraph interface, which is documented here (for v3.6): http://www.info.uni-karlsruhe.de/software/grgen/doc/API_3_6/html/T_de_unika_ipd_grGen_libGr_IGraph.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get all nodes/edges of the current graph using the `Nodes` and `Edges` properties.

Try this out:

```py
edgeList = graph.Edges
nodeList = graph.Nodes
```

Afterwards you can iterate over these lists `for node in nodeList:` and sort out the elements having the attributes you wanna change, e.g. `if node.myAttribute == 42:`.